# populating php dropdown options with mysql result values shows "Array" when I sort() the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dropdown

Edit: When I commented out the `sort()` line, now it is populating properly.  PHP sort looks in-place so I don't know what happened.

I also had to insert a redundant `<div>` right above the form to either get the array of option values from a session variable or calling the querying function to get it populated.

```
<?php
                    $food_options_arr = [];
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['food-options-arr'])){
                        $food_options_arr = get_food_options();
                    }
                    else{
                        $food_options_arr = get_food_options();
                    }
                    for($i=0; $i<count($food_options_arr); $i+=1){
                        //echo "{$food_options_arr[$i]}";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Coming from Python, this feels very weird and somewhat clunky.

First I thought it was my problem using associative arrays so I used a linear array to store my query results.
My query:

```
$sql = "SELECT species from lunchbox WHERE 1=1";
```

I saw somewhere on S.O. that 1=1 will not hurt performance so left it in.

When I call the querying function in my view page and step through on debugger, I can clearly see the array holds the correct query results:

[image: food_array in debugger]

And I also checked each value of `$food` in the array to make sure it was there.

Then I try to populate the dropdown following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189689/13865853
or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43334388/13865853

But all I get are values of "Array" as dropdown options.

[image: Array only]

My code:

```
                  <form action="">
                    <label class="dropdown-label">Choose Food:</label>
                    <br>
                    <select id="food-dropdown" name="food-option">
                        <?php
                        $food_options_arr = array();
                        if(!isset($_SESSION['food-options-arr'])){
                            $food_options_arr = get_food_options();
                        }
                        else{
                            $food_options_arr = $_SESSION['food-options-arr'];
                        }
                        //$food_options_arr = array_unique($food_options_arr);
                        sort($food_options_arr);
                        foreach($food_options_arr as $food){
                            echo "<option value='". $food ."'>" . $food . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>

                        <option selected="selected">
                            <?php echo "$food_options_arr[0]";?>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was:

```
                    foreach($metabollite_options_arr as $sci_name){
                            $trim_name = trim($sci_name, "[]?");
                            str_replace("/", " ", $trim_name);
                            if($trim_name != ""){
                                echo "<option value={strtolower($trim_name)}>$trim_name</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
```

so using `{}` to enclose the variable.
However, I was unable to `trim()` nor `str_replace()` the `/`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='strtolower($sci_name)'>$sci_name</option>";
```

single quotes don't execute the PHP code, good practice is to close the PHP and write html and echo valuable in it.

```
<option selected="selected">
    <?php echo $food_options_arr[0];?>
</option>
```